# mongoose: how to find all data with querying array of object?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "personalities": [
        {
            "personalName": "something",
            "color":0,
            "total":0,
            "userId":""
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to find with this method:

```
User.find({personalities:{
        $$elemMatch:{
            personalName:"something"
        }
    }})
        .then(users => res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(users)))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err))
```

Edit:
code {"personalities.personalName":"something"} work on mongoDbCompass.
[image]

but when i query with mongoose. it return all of docs.

```
app.post("/users", (req, res) => {
    User.find({"personalities.personalName":"something"})
        .then(users => res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(users.length)))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err))
})
```

but it returns all documents (even documents with personalName not equal "something"). how can I fix it?

I really appreciate your help and hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The perfect method is to use **findById** method. Just pass the user id and get all its relevant details like below.

```
User.findById(userId).then(user=> //do something here).catch(err=> console.log(err)
```

However, if you don't have Id you can get the single user by matching the user details using **findOne** method. You can find reference here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne.

```
User.findOne({  personalName:"something" }).then(user=> //do something).catch(err=>console.log(err)
```

Further, there is possibility that there are multiple records with matching where clause, in that case (and better) you should go for **find** Method. It works something like below.

```
// find all documents
await MyModel.find({});

// find all documents named john and at least 18
await MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 } }).exec();

// executes, passing results to callback
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});

// executes, name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends').exec();

// passing options
await MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, null, { skip: 10 }).exec();
```

Last but not least, if there is array inside the document and you want to search by targeting objects inside the array then we can easily accomplish this.

```
User.find(
    { "personalities.personalName": "something"  }
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
    }
  );
```

**or something like below with callback**

```
User.find({ "personalities.personalName": "something"  `})
.then(users=> //do something with users).catch(error=>console.log(error))`
```

Comment: thanks so much but i want to find wth querying array of object , i look your comment but i don't see it.what i missed?

Comment: I just made an edit to my answer and have a look at the last answer. I hope that is something you are looking for

Comment: I also tried it but it still return all doc.

Comment: Do you have any way?

Comment: does it return only the docs matching "something" or all the docs ?

Comment: it return all the docs. your code { "personalities.personalName": "something"} work on MongodbCompass. but when query by mongoose, it not work even same code. i just made an edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

As in your current attempt, `$elemMatch` is used. I take an assumption of you need to find all documents where there is one matched entry of `"personalName": "something"` in the `personalities` array.

A simple `find` should suffice.

```
db.collection.find({
  "personalities.personalName": "something"
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eWr9lUYz_eV) for your reference.

Comment: when i use your code on MongoDbCompass , it work. but when i use with mongoose , it doesn't. i just edited my post. can you give me a minute? thanks so much